# WindowsでMecabをHerokuにデプロイできない

Tags: python, windows, heroku, mecab

WindowsでMeCabを使ったアプリをherokuにデプロイしたいのですが、エラーが出ます。

```
remote:        Collecting mecab-python-windows==0.996.3 (from -r 
/tmp/build_beb169f7c63c4d7023b0ec6888f38c1f/requirements.txt (line 5))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/40/c9/437d18e868da1e4c49cee00594992de2fdd4008d63c6ef303eaae796ab34/mecab-python-windows-0.996.3.tar.gz (53kB)
remote:            Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:    
remote:            /bin/sh: 1: mecab-config: not found
remote:            Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:              File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-build-y1h8lx3p/mecab-python- 
windows/setup.py", line 46, in <module>
remote:                include_dirs=cmd2("mecab-config --inc-dir"),
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-build-y1h8lx3p/mecab-python- 
windows/setup.py", line 14, in cmd2
remote:                return cmd1(strings).split()
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-build-y1h8lx3p/mecab-python- 
windows/setup.py", line 10, in cmd1
remote:                return os.popen(strings).readlines()[0][:-1]
remote:            IndexError: list index out of range
remote:
remote:            ----------------------------------------
remote:        Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 
in /tmp/pip-build-y1h8lx3p/mecab-python-windows/
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
```

ローカルのMeCabはhttps://qiita.com/menon/items/f041b7c46543f38f78f7を参考にしてrequirest.txtにmecab-python-windowsと記述しています。どうすればいいのでしょうか

Comment: 目的が違うようですが、これが参考になるかも。[Herokuでpython+mecab+ffmpegを使う](https://qiita.com/Sashimimochi/items/2da79bda71dfc1b555cd)

Comment: エラーメッセージの中に `/bin/sh: 1: mecab-config: not found` とあるので、Heroku のサーバに `mecab-config` コマンドがインストールされていないのでしょう。それと、[WindowsやmacやLinuxにpipでPython用MeCabバインディングをいれる](https://qiita.com/yukinoi/items/990b6933d9f21ba0fb43) を読むと、「過去にmecab-python-windowsというものを公開しましたが、そちらは今後アップデートしないつもりなので、mecab-python-windowsを使っている人はこちらに乗り換えることを推奨します。」と書かれています。

Comment: @metropolis pipで対応していたものをインストールしましたが、同じエラーでした。Herokuサーバーにmecab-configがない場合は諦めるしかないのでしょうか？

Comment: 同じエラーに遭遇した方が [herokuでpython+django+scikit-learn+mecab(1)](https://qiita.com/kenchin110100/items/6f1c84ac8858525fffc5) という記事を書かれています。「そこでmecab-pythonはheroku上で手動でインストールする」という記載があるので参考にしてみてはどうでしょうか。